# How to find a key and value exist in a object and apply css for them in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

Am having an object like below:

```
var obj = {
0: {id:'1001',name:'john'},
1: {id:'1002',name:'johnson'},
2: {id:'1001',name:'jack'},
3: {id:'1021',name:'mark'},
}
```

I need to find in the object that has key,value pair as id: 1001 and apply the css properties such as background color.

This object will be like a html table. I just did a sample object so no need to check duplicates. My html table will have two columns ID and Name. So based on the value i want to apply css for the entire row.

Comment: Objects composed of primitives like that do not have CSS properties you can set.

Comment: ..........What?

Comment: CSS properties to what? CSS gets applied to HTML elements not data. Please show code samples of what you intend to achieve.

Comment: Where are the `CSS` properties.... Also what have you tried? So far you haven't really provided anything of any use. **Also** You have a duplicate `id` **1001** which isn't much of an ID since ID's are supposed to be a unique identity.

Comment: This object will be like a html table. I just did a sample object so no need to check duplicates. My html table will have two columns ID and Name. So based on the value i want to apply css for the entire row.

Comment: @binDebug check my updated question

Comment: @CertainPerformance check my updated question

Comment: It's very difficult to confidently give an answer without being able to see the actual HTML. The HTML is relevant to the question, so please post it in an edit to your question.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps.

```js
var obj = {
0: {id:'1001',name:'john'},
1: {id:'1002',name:'johnson'},
2: {id:'1001',name:'jack'},
3: {id:'1021',name:'mark'},
}
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(element) {
  if(obj[element]["id"] == 1001){
      console.log(obj[element]["name"]);
  }
});
```

Edit: your comment makes your question more clear. I hope this example gives you what you need to implement your needs. `P.s. People need to chill out with the down votes.`

```js
let table = document.getElementById("exTable").children[0];
for(var i = 1; i<table.children.length; i++){
    if(table.children[i].children[1].innerHTML == "Rafi"){
        table.children[i].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>
<table style="width:100%" id="exTable" border="1">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Rafi</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Quinn</td>
  </tr>
<tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you understand the question?

Comment: If you need both the key and the value, `Object.entries()` is way doper that `Object.keys()`.. Check it out!

Comment: This object will be like a html table. I just did a sample object so no need to check duplicates. My html table will have two columns ID and Name. So based on the value i want to apply css for the entire row.

Comment: Don't mix `var` and `let`. Preferably, always use `const`.